# Customize bootstrap file upload component

Tags: bootstrap-5

The bootstrap file upload skin looks like below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s9kQ.jpg

Is there a way to change the button text from "Choose Files" to something else and put the button to right instead of left?

Comment: Bootstrap just styles the existing content in the `<input>` element that is provided by the browser itself, so it's not part of the DOM. Truly customizing the appearance is usually done by hiding the actual `<input>` and showing a custom `<label>` with the `for` attribute pointing to the (hidden) `<input>`. The label then works as a button.